# Moving a container's elements

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, move

My understanding of move semantics is that you should declare the function's parameters as by-value but make a call to `std::move` when you are interested in owning an object. This lets the compiler decide if the object should be copied or moved.

How do you allow the compiler to make a similar optimization when you are only interested in the object's contents, without making unnecessary copies of the container or it's elements. So for example if I have some function which takes an array of 3 objects and stores them in it's own container, how do I let the compiler decide if it should move or copy the elements?

```
class foo {
    std::vector<BigObject> objects;

public:
    void set_objects(std::array<BigObject, 3> input) {
        // Store the input's elements in the objects vector
    }
};
```

I read about `std::make_move_iterator` but I am unsure whether this forces a move and how this effects the input or how the input parameter should be defined.

For example if `set_objects`'s body looked like so:

```
objects = std::vector<BigObject>(
    std::make_move_iterator(input.begin()),
    std::make_move_iterator(input.end())
);
```

I believe `objects` would now be a vector containing `input`'s elements and `input` would now be empty. That's desired if `input` was an xvalue but the signature declares `input` as by-value so was the original container copied even if it was an xvalue as nowhere do I say to move the actual container, just it's elements.

I can declare `input` as by-reference to prevent the copying but then if `std::make_move_iterator` forces a move there could be side effects if `input` was an lvalue?

Having typed out my question I believe the answer is to overload `set_objects` with an xvalue and by-reference signature, the former moving `input`'s elements and the later copying `input`'s elements but I do not feel confident enough to say that is the correct solution.

Comment: What's the distinction between moving/copying an array of 3 objects, and moving/copying 3 objects?

Comment: The compiler doesn't generally decide anything. The *programmer* decides what they want their program to do.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `foo` may want to expand beyond the initial 3 elements but only allow an initial 3 elements. You could accept a vector and move that vector but then you have to perform runtime checks to ensure you were only given 3 elements in the new vector. You then have to decide on the behaviour when you get more than 3 elements. This guarantees the input to be 3 elements at compile time which I feel is a lot more elegant.

Comment: @KerrekSB Whilst I agree with the sentiment part of programming is knowing what the compiler can do for you. Instead of writing out multiple signatures for every method I can write one and know that the compiler will perform any necessary explosion. There is of course cases where you should be explicit but that goes back to my original point of knowing what the compiler can do for you.